# What is the format of string out put in mPDF? and how to read the string generated by mPDF?

Tags: mpdf

When you are using mPDF to generate output PDF as string as stated in documentation ($mpdf->Output('', "S");) , what is the format of that string (ex, base68) and how to read them in front-end or convert them to something that can be used to view pdf in front-end.

Comment: I would imagine the format is PDF, no more conversion needed. By "base68" I'm guessing you mean "base64", but there's no reason for a PDF library to encode its output that way.

Comment: Yo were right, I treated as pdf and tried to change it to base64 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The string output is a plaintext/binary combination stream of the resulting PDF document. You read it with a PDF viewer directly.